# Image Paralax Full Window Display

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how to word this question so apologies I will try to explain as best I can. I'm trying to make an image display to the full width and height of the users browser window. With parallax scrolling so its a one page website when you load it, it will have this image and a h1 then parallax scrolling down to the content of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
img{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZwULG/)

Comment: Thanks this is great it has added a bottom scroll bar having the widthvw, but hasn't with width:100%; will 100% work fine?

Comment: percentage take width/height of it's parent not browser width/height. use `overflow:hidden` for prevent scroll